# What is the purpose of 'properties' field in Metaplex Token Standard?

Tags: metaplex, metadata, json

The non-fungible standard mentioned here: [Metaplex Docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard) has 'properties' field in its example. What is the purpose of this field? Is it required for the collection to add this field in its NFTs?

Answer (score 1):

for the most part, it's used **for additional related files**. it also held an **NFT category type**.

```
"properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/abcd5678?ext=png",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://watch.videodelivery.net/9876jkl",
        "type": "unknown",
        "cdn": true
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/efgh1234?ext=mp4",
        "type": "video/mp4"
      }
    ],
    "category": "video",

    // @deprecated
    // Do not use - may be removed in a future release.
    // Use on-chain data instead.
    "collection": {
      "name": "Solflare X NFT",
      "family": "Solflare"
    },

    // @deprecated
    // Do not use - may be removed in a future release.
    // Use on-chain data instead.
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "xEtQ9Fpv62qdc1GYfpNReMasVTe9YW5bHJwfVKqo72u",
        "share": 100
      }
    ]
  }
```